# Windows 8 Web Authentication Broker can't connect to the service

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, single-sign-on, windows-store-apps

Can Web Authentication Broker be used with a non oAuth authentication ?

I have created an Asp.Net MVC2 website with a login page that I want to use through Web Authentication Broker to retrieve and persist the authentication cookie.

Here is the code :

```
WebAuthenticationResult WebAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(
WebAuthenticationOptions.None,
new Uri("https://localhost:44301/Account/LogOn"),
new Uri("https://localhost:44301/"));
```

When loaded the WAB returns the following message "Can't connect to the service" and when looking to the event viewer there is a navigation error event.

Is something wrong with my code or there is no way to connect to a cookie based login page ?

Answer (score 0):

Web Authentication Broker is meant for WinRT applications.

In your case you have several options.

1. Use [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net) directly
2. Upgrade to MVC4 and use the support provided via ASP.NET 4.5's addition of the oAuth functionality included in the default templates. See [Using oAuth Providers with MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc)
   It's super easy to integrate into your MVC app.